# Please Help Why my application crash with the following error:?

Tags: ios

I get this error:

> [NSIndexPath row]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x13135d50

my code:

```
 -(void) scrollViewDidFinishScrolling: (UIScrollView*) scrollView {
     CGPoint point = [self convertPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.0, kDefaultCellHeight/2.0) toView:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath* centerIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

     [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: centerIndexPath
                            animated: YES
                      scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop];

     if (centerIndexPath.row != self.currentIndex.row) {
         //Hide the arrow when scrolling
         [self setCurrentIndex:centerIndexPath];
     }

     [self.arrow show:YES];
```

Comment: `self.currentIndex` must have been deallocated, how do you have it declared/created?

Comment: Can you repeat the problem in the debugger?

Comment: The message says it.  You invoked "row" on a pointer that no longer points to a valid object.  Presumably the problem pointer is currentIndex, and the likely cause is that it was not properly retained.  But you need to run the analyzer and do some debugging to nail it down.

Comment: Without any further context, I would guess that you defined `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSIndexPath *currentIndex;`  That should be `strong` or `retain`.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a deallocated variable, the `NSIndexPath` `self.currentRow`.  Somewhere (else) in your code you're gaining a reference to it but not retaining it - if you do so you should no longer see this error.  Just make sure to release it when it's no longer needed.

Comment: It seems like it could just as likely be a issue with `self.currentIndex`.

Comment: @BrianNickel Yeah, I already updated my answer to say so.  Thanks.

Comment: If using ARC, then centerIndexPath should be strongly retained, so it is likely to be self.currentIndex, which might be a weak reference.

Comment: In either case `centerIndexPath` is a locally declared variable, it shouldn't have gone out of scope, and it was gotten from a tableview method, it is incredibly unlikely that it has been deallocated.  Not to mention that `row` is not invoked on `centerIndexPath`

Comment: @DanF Ha, right. I actually overlooked that `centerIndexPath` was declared inside the block.  I've updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: I think my problem is that the code is in ARC but my project is not build with ARC

Answer (score 0):

Make sure currentIndex is a retained property if not using ARC (or strong if using ARC). Since indexPathForRowAtPoint: returns an autoreleased object, you need to retain it if you're keeping it around to use elsewhere.